# How to introduce multiple variables in graph.run() through python?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

hi I am sort of new to py2neo which is supposed to be supported by neo4j community

I just wanted to do a

`graph.run("MATCH (a) - [:{x}]-> (b) WHERE b.name = {y}
               RETURN b.name "  ).to_table()`

but wanted to use two variables `x,y` in run() which I could pass onto using as a function parameter in python, wasn't able to find out any sort of documentation on this.
Would really appreciate some direction or help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cypher doesn't accept relationship types as query parameters.**

You can not pass x as a parameter here, I would suggest you create a **query string in python with x** as a parameter and then pass **y as a parameter in a run()**.

Something like:

```
query_string = "MATCH (a) - [:%s]-> (b) WHERE b.name = {y} RETURN b.name " % (x)
```

And **pass y as a parameter to run()** method:

```
graph.run(query_string, {"y":y}).to_table()
```